# Using generics with entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, oop, generics

In `PersonBusiness.GetQuery` method, the `PersonEntity` is peppered all over code and there are a lot of other entity types that will implement this method similarly.

I want to use generic parameters in PersonBusiness to lessen usage of specific entity type because there will be implementations like this one with other entities and i want to prevent some other type used instead of the intended entity type. But could not be successful or satisfied by generic parameter used versions.

I also want to use interfaces instead of concrete classes if it is more meaningful.

```
public class Entities: DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<PersonEntity> PersonSet { get; set; }
}
public class PersonEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class BaseBusiness
{
    public Entities Db => new Entities();
}

public abstract class BaseBusiness<T> : BaseBusiness where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderBy)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Db.Set<T>();
        if (where != null)
            query = query.Where(where);
        if (orderBy != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);

        return query;
    }

    public abstract IQueryable<T> ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(IQueryable<T> query);

    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(IQueryable<T> query, string orderBy, Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> defaultOrderBy = null)
    {
        if (orderBy != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        else
            query = defaultOrderBy != null ? defaultOrderBy(query) : ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(query);

        return query;
    }
}

public class PersonBusiness : BaseBusiness<PersonEntity>
{
    public IQueryable<PersonEntity> GetQuery(string orderBy, int? groupId)
    {
        IQueryable<PersonEntity> query = Db.PersonSet;

        Func<IQueryable<PersonEntity>, IQueryable<PersonEntity>> defaultOrderBy = null;
        if (groupId.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(d => d.Id == groupId);
        }
        else
        {
            defaultOrderBy = q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Id).ThenBy(d => d.FullName);
        }
        return GetQuery(query, orderBy, defaultOrderBy);
    }
    public override IQueryable<PersonEntity> ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(IQueryable<PersonEntity> query)
    {
        return query.OrderBy(q => q.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what issue are you having?

Comment: It does not compile, incompatibility between IQueryable<T> and IQueryable<PersonEntity>. Casting resolves it but there are a lot of casts in that case so it smells. I think it should be designed differently.

Comment: Title of your post is Generic.

Comment: Your code looks like the Repository Anti-Pattern. Consider a different design. What problem is your `BaseBusiness<T>` class meant to solve? What does it encapsulate, exactly?

Comment: I don't want to use repository pattern because I think ef already (so some other people thinks that way) does that job so it is similar to repository but i just want to return queries not results.

Comment: Nikhil Vartak generics could be used but may be some different way, not the way it is in this code.

Comment: These GetQuery and ApplyDefault functions appear to add little to no value.  The logic is basically redundant to what can be done directly against the DbSet via 1 line Linq statements.  If I were you, I'd consider completely ignoring them in favor of trying to write the Linq against the DbSet directly, and see what that looks like.  I'd bet you end up deleting these "GetQuery" constructs from your code.

Comment: Your question is too broad, unclear and opnion-based, with or without a bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite my comment on the post, I figured I'd put an answer up here which compiles.  As I don't understand the use case, it's hard to reason about a proper solution.  Never-the-less here is the code

```
public class PersonBusiness<T> : BaseBusiness<T> where T: PersonEntity
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(string orderBy, int? groupId)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Db.Set<T>();

        Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> defaultOrderBy = null;
        if (groupId.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(d => d.Id == groupId);
        }
        else
        {
            defaultOrderBy = q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Id).ThenBy(d => d.FullName);
        }
        return GetQuery(query, orderBy, defaultOrderBy);
    }
    public override IQueryable<T> ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.OrderBy(q => q.FullName);
    }
}
```

Updated to use DbSet in favor of Cast, per the comment from @Ivan Stoev.

Comment: @lockedscope You are using the word *type inference* several times in your comments. But that term applies for generic methods, while here you are inside a generic class. So all the methods are associated with the type `T` which you **have** to resolve before even able to call them, e.g. the intended usage is something like `var pb = new PersonBusiness<PersonEntity>(); pb.GetQuery(...)`. So there is no type inference involved in your design. What about constraints, they **do** allow you to access the `Id` and `FullName` properties of `T`. Both interface and base class would work.

Comment: So Jeffrey's code definitely compiles (it's another story if it's what you are after, which is quite unclear from your question). The only change I would suggest is to use `DbSet<T>()` instead of `Db.PersonSet.Cast<T>()`.

Comment: Sorry, i mixed up things, it actually compiles.

Comment: Updated to include the suggestion from @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0):

I pulled out PersonEntity into an interface and used a type constraint to require that T implement IPersonEntity.  I don't see the point of what you're doing, but it seems like you want to use type constraints and just haven't heard of them before.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

```
public interface IPersonEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class PersonBusiness<T> where T : IPersonEntity
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(string orderBy, int? groupId)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Db.PersonSet;
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> defaultOrderBy = null;
        if (groupId.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(d => d.Id == groupId);
        }
        else
        {
            defaultOrderBy = q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Id).ThenBy(d => d.FullName);
        }
        return GetQuery(query, orderBy, defaultOrderBy);
    }
    public IQueryable<T> ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.OrderBy(q => q.FullName);
    }
    public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(IQueryable<T> query, string orderBy, Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> defaultOrderBy = null)
    {
        if (orderBy != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        else
            query = defaultOrderBy != null ? defaultOrderBy(query) : ApplyDefaultOrderyBy(query);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not compile because constraints are not used for type inference

Comment: I actually didn't try to compile the code.  Does it work when you don't use type inference?

Comment: It does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

As Dai comments. This approach breaks repository pattern. My solution is create an Generic Repository exactly as Julie Lerman explain in [ef architecture](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/efarchitecture)

A post with the pattern implementation is in [ef-code-first-you-on-repository](http://www.blogtech.hipalanet.com/2017/01/12/ef-code-first-you-on-repository/)

This snippet could help.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
        public DbContext Context { get; protected set; }

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            this.Context = new AppDbContext();
        }

        public BaseRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            var query = Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            return query;
        }

        public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry(T entity)
        {
            return this.Context.Entry(entity);
        }

        public virtual void InsertOrUpdate(params T[] entities)
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                this.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            this.Context.SetCurrentStateToEntities();
            this.Context.SaveChanges();

            this.Context.SetToUndefined();
        }
    }
```